# Swapping data rows between two tables in angular using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a sample angular app where i have taken a popup component.

In my popup component i have taken two tables ,the first table contains the list data rows and the second table is empty.

I have implemented swapping functionality between the tables.

on clicking the **Move to second table** button on first table , the selected rows should be transferred to the second table.

And on clicking the **Move to first table** button on second table, the selected rows should be transferred to the first table.

But I am getting an issue during swapping the data rows.If I make a selectAll in the first table and click on the button **Move to second table**, the rows are being tansferred.

But initially after opening the popup if I just select 2 or 3 rows and transfer, the selected rows are being transferred but the remaining rows in the first table are getting deleted.....!

please access my [sample app here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-gnhq6e?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts)

Can any body please tell what is that i am missing .....?

Answer (score 1):

In your `moveToSecondTable()` function, your data copy operation relies on the `isSelected` property which doesn't exist, so the `isSelected === false` check fails because `undefined` is not equal to `false`. You could easily fix that by using a less strict comparison and just checking for truthiness such as `isSelected == false` or just `!isSelected`:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.uncheckedData.filter(x => !x.isSelected));
```

But the root cause of the problem is that your data model defined in `Element` does not include an `isSelected` property. The best fix is to add the property to the model and provide a default value:

```
export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  isSelected: boolean
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', isSelected: false },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He', isSelected: false },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li', isSelected: false },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be', isSelected: false },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B', isSelected: false }
];
```